# How does the Doom Guy trigger the Soul Cube?

Tags: video-games, doom, doom-3

From the [Doom wiki](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cube), when we first pick up the Soul Cube, it tells us:

> Destroying evil gives us life, and makes us stronger. Unleash us when you hear our call. We will pass the life force of those we slay to you. We foresee a great battle, but the outcome is not clear. We are the only way to destroy Hell's mightiest warrior.

And every time it is charged we hear:

> Use us!

What is the in-universe explanation for how the Soul Cube is actually triggered? How does the Doom Guy communicate to the Soul Cube he wants it to activate?

Answer (score 3):

In-universe:

> The Cube does not have a physical firing mechanism, but it follows the
>   wishes of its owner precisely.

Out-universe:

> The Soul Cube attacks intelligently; it always attacks the enemy with
>   the largest amount of hit points within range, and homes in on the
>   target.

The above and Further information can be found on the [doom wiki](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cube).

[This site](http://www.andywest.org/pr/doom3/doom3weapons.html) on Doom 3 weapons says:

> When it is ready (by telling you Use us!) you throw it at an enemy like an Archvile or Hellknight.

If this is the in-universe explanation, wouldn't it be too easy to trigger? Perhaps it requires the throwing action combined with the "wishes of it's owner".

Comment: It would be good to add an excerpt from the wiki which supports and details on your "in-universe" claim regarding the firing mechanism.

Comment: I'll make it clearer, both explanations are excerpts from the wiki

Comment: I see. Well, the doom wiki doesn't quote any sources and I don't remember it being stated in the game how the trigger works (hence the question).

Comment: Added another link to a page, though there's no citation of sources there either, there probably isn't an officially cited explanation.